# Unable to upload Xamarin's built to App Store

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, app-store

I followed the documents given below to upload the xamarin's built to Appstore:

Documents Followed : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=windows
But could not upload due to following reasons:

Everytime i tried to upload the binaries/built. It says "No Valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain".

Can anybody help in finding the proper doc, following which i can upload xamarin built to Appstore

Attached below are screenshot
[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't have the distribution certificate installed on the machine, only a developer certificate. You cannot use that to sign and distribute your iOS app with.

Comment: Read this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=windows#provisioningprofile